# matplotlib - How do I adjust the y axis scale to something more appropriate?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Right now I'm using:

```
self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
....
self.axes.relim()
self.axes.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
```

To rescale all four lines that I have in this plot:

[image]

The problem I have is that majority of the time, the green and red current lines are really far apart and basically sit on the top and bottom of the graph window for most of the time (when the current does't deviate too much)

How do I make it the axis a bit higher than the highest current and a bit lower than the lowest  current to ensure that the current lines are more readable?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered doing it "by hand" using `axes.set_ylim` with values you find appropriate ? (Side note: your colors are a mess, I can't understand which graph correspond to which axis)

Comment: Sorry about the colours, ongoing project.

I can do it by hand, but the problem is that the values of current can vary dramatically that my manually set ylim would have to be very large and I will end up in the same situation as I am in now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ax.margins()](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins) method to add some margin to the axes. E.g.

```
ax.margins(y=0.07)
```

adds a 7% vertical margin on both ends of the y axis scale.

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `self.axes.set_ylim([1,4])`. Also I think you may consider add legends to the figure by `self.axes.legend()`.

Comment: See my comment on the initial post